# Convert list of non-generic objects to a list of generic objects

Tags: c#, generics, caching

I have a base entity:

```
public class BaseEntity<TPrimary>
{
    public T Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    // + other methods ...
}
```

Together with:

```
public class BaseEntityManager<TBaseEntity, TPrimaryKey>
    where TBaseEntity : BaseEntity<TPrimary> { ... }
```

Also, I have the following 2 classes that I use to put data in cache:

```
public class BaseEntityCacheItem
{
    public List<BaseEntityCacheItem> Items {get; set;}
}

public class BaseEntitySingleCacheItem
{
    public object Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;} 
}
```

Now, inside the manager, I want to return all items from Database. First I check, if they are in the Cache so I return them, otherwise I access the Database.

The problem is now when reading from Cache, I will read a `BaseEntityCacheItem` that has a property `Items` of type `List<BaseEntitySingleCacheItem>`.

How to be able to convert a `List<BaseEntitySingleCacheItem>` to `List<TBaseEntity<TPrimary>>`.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
var entity = await GetListFromCacheAsync();
var instances = new List<TBaseEntity>();
foreach(BaseEntitySingleCacheItem in entity.Items)
{
    instances.Add(new BaseEntity<TPrimaryKey> { Id =  e.Id } );
}
return instances;
```

so the idea is to return the list of objects in Cache at runtime after determining the `TPrimary` and `TBaseEntity`.

Comment: I suppose you already considered make your BaseEntityCacheItem generic ? Accepting a TBaseEntity ?

Comment: Actually no, I will try this now and see how it goes.

Comment: The point is, BaseEntity has some methods and that's why I created a separate CacheItem to just use the basic fields not more.

Comment: Have you tried to play with interface then ? Implement this specific interface to both your base entity and cache item ?

Comment: The last piece of code you gave does not work ?

Comment: _"BaseEntityCacheItem that has a property Items of type List<BaseEntitySingleCacheItem>"_ -- that is not what the code you posted shows. Did you mean to write `public List<BaseEntitySingleCacheItem> Items {get; set;}` instead? More generally, why have the `BaseEntitySingleCacheItem` type at all? Why not make the cache generic and use the type you want? I.e. `BaseEntity<TPrimaryKey>`?

Comment: I meant not to use the BaseEntity<TPrimaryKey> as it holds some methods etc. Thought of using something else that is pure properties. Now I changed my code, I am able to work around the above, but for some reason the Manager now is not being picked up by IOC, I am digging to know what's going on! Thanks